# How can I define dependencies between INSTALLS targets in qmake?

Tags: qt, installation, qmake, depends

I have several modules that I want to install (make install step) using qmake's INSTALLS: INSTALLS = module1 module2 module3. These install from different source folders, to same destination folder tree. Till now all nice and good...

But when running "make install -j 3", sometimes, I was getting: "cp: cannot create directory ‘/my/target/folder/’: File exists

Can I define some dependency between the modules, so module2 is installed only when installing module1 is finished?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, I used [this article](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35669-Packaging-with-the-qmake-INSTALLS-variable). So if anyone is in the same situation, the solution looks like this:

`module1.path = /my/target/folder
module1.files = /my/source/folder1/subFolder1`

`module2.path = /my/target/folder
module2.files = /my/source/folder1/subFolder1/subfolder2
module2.depends = install_module1` # the "install_" prefix is the key to this

`INSTALLS = module1 module2`

I hope this helps someone avoid my struggle...